# how to work with scheduling in ccnet config

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am working in cruise control. I want,my window service should be make a build every day twice aroud morning 9 am and evening 7 pn.how to set all my senario on  in ccnet.config.below is my ccnet.config

```
 <project name="aaa">
    <webURL>http://localhost:333/ccnet/</webURL>

    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger seconds="300" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
    </triggers>

    <tasks>

     </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [scheduleTrigger](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Schedule_Trigger):

```
<project name="aaa">
    <webURL>http://localhost:333/ccnet/</webURL>

    <triggers>
        <scheduleTrigger time="9:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
        <scheduleTrigger time="19:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
    </triggers>

    <tasks />

 </project>
```

Comment: hi..i have used same same but it's not firing.wht;should i do